# SQL Server 2008 stored procedure that processes 1000+ records cuts of in middle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a bit of a problem in SQL Server 2008. I have a front-end form that sends item type and quantity. Then SQL Server would produce IDS that equal the number of the given quantity for the given items. So the input is like:

```
Laptop 1000
UPS 10
```

The above wouldn't work cos laptops are 1000. But the following works:

```
laptop 300
ups 350
desktop 300
calculator 300
...
```

The sum can go beyond 1000 as long as the individual items are below 350

Portion of the code I have is:

```
DECLARE @ids varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @currentid varchar(15)
DECLARE @begin int = 0
DECLARE @intgenwhat smallint -- GENERATE A NUMBER OR A LETTER?
DECLARE @currentidlength smallint

DECLARE @ownercode varchar(3) = 'ABC'

BEGIN
SET

while @begin < @p1
BEGIN
    SET @currentid = ''
    SET @currentidlength = LEN(@currentid + @callercode)

    while @currentidlength < 15
    BEGIN
        SET @intgenwhat = FLOOR(2 * rand())

        if @intgenwhat = 0
            SET @currentid = @currentid + cast(char(FLOOR(10 * rand()) + 48 ) as varchar)
        else
            SET @currentid = @currentid + cast(char(FLOOR(10 * rand()) + 65) as varchar)

        SET @currentidlength = @currentidlength + 1
    END 

    SET @ids = @ids + @ownercode + @callercode +  @currentid + ','
    SET @begin = @begin + 1
END 

--remove last ,
SET @ids = dbo.DSSMSFN_strRemoveCharacters(@ids, 1, len(@ids) - 1)

END

SELECT @companyids = @ids
```

It works as expected. It returns the needed IDs in CSV. But if quantity of a single type is more than 350, it gets stuck and returns nothing. The sum of single types can be greater than 1000 even and its result is as expected.

Is it a timeout issue? I can't understand whats happening at all since the total quantity can be higher and it works but fails if a single type quantity is higher.

Edit: As requested here is an additional info

My tables are:

- `tblmain`: invoiceid, invoicenumber, invoicedate
- `tblitems`: itemid, invoicecode [FK], itemtype, itemcode

Now the invoices (in paper) are:

```
Invoice Number: 8888888 Date: 2015-08-05

Laptop 100
Camera 20
.
.
.


Invoice Number: 6666666 Date: 2015-08-05

Laptop 100
Camera 20
.
.
.
```

The program adds the invoice and creates ID numbers for the items that arrived one by one and prints their ID numbers afterwards. The stored procedure takes number of items that arrived and creates a 15 characters long unique ID and returns CSV. For e.g. for the 20 cameras, it sends back 20 CSV IDS that the calling procedure inserts into the `tblitems` table one by one.

It is typically a fast procedure for any number of items as long as no single item is greater than 350 or so. But if you have a better idea, please share.

Comment: On the first sight I'm quite sure, that your approach is to complicated, but please provide some more details (expected output, involved tables...)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters (including in the `CAST` statements!) that you use - otherwise you might end up with an unexpected surprise of a `varchar` defaulting to a length of **1 character** - usually not what you want....